# Getting wrong week number of given date

Tags: java, time

I have tried the following example. If I pass the mentioned dates, it should return the 3rd week, but it is returning the 2nd week. What is wrong in my code? Please help me in this regard.

```
public class weekNumberCount {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Timestamp  startTime = new Timestamp(2016, 05, 17, 00, 00, 00, 00);
        Timestamp  endTime = new Timestamp(2016,06, 06, 23, 59, 59, 00); 
        Timestamp  givenDateString = new Timestamp(2016, 06, 01, 00, 00, 00, 00);

        if (givenDateString.compareTo(startTime) < 0 || givenDateString.compareTo(endTime) > 0) {
            System.out.println("Not a Valid Date"); 
        }

        System.out.println((int)(((givenDateString.getTime() - startTime.getTime() - 1)/(1000L * 3600 * 24 * 7)) + 1));  
    }
}
```

Comment: At a first glance, I see that the given logic is calculating the number of weeks between May 17 and June 01. And it is 2 weeks. Let us know if you are trying to achieve something else. May 17 is 3 weeks away from May 01.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your code is you are subtracting extra `1` from the difference of two dates. What should you do is take the difference of these two dates which is coming to 2 weeks and then add 1 which marks the start of third week

Hence you should only need

```
((givenDateString.getTime() - startTime.getTime())/(1000L * 3600 * 24 * 7))+1
```

**Update:**

There is an issue with understanding as well. in Java all months are `0` based so it works like :

> Jan - 0
>
> Feb - 1
>
> .
>
> .
>
> Dec - 11

So pass months accordingly in your code and calculate week by taking `ceil` of the difference like this.

```
System.out.println(Math.ceil((givenDateString.getTime() - startTime
                    .getTime()) / (1000d * 3600 * 24 * 7)));
```

One more thing is you are using deprecated constructor of `Timestamp` class instead use a `Calendar` object to do the task.

Hope it helps.

Comment: check for startTime - 2016, 04, 25 and givenDateString - 2016, 05,01.this gives week as 2 but it is week 1.